# Fetching all base URLs from site config in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

In an extension we build for TYPO3 8 we check if a URL entered by a user is a local URL by checking the domain against records in the `sys_domain` table. We're now updating that extension for TYPO3 9 and 10. `sys_domain` has been deprecated in TYPO3 9 and removed in 10. It has been replaced with settings in the site configuration.

Is there an easy way to fetch all known base URLs (including variants and languages) from the site configuration without parsing and looping through the site configuration myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You need to use the [PHP API: Accessing Site Configuration](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/AccessingSiteConfiguration.html)

here is an example:

```
$siteFinder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SiteFinder::class);
$allsites = $siteFinder->getAllSites();
```

This is the results

[image]

Best regards